# Xcode crash on opening storyboard

Tags: ios, xcode, xamarin, uistoryboard

I am developing an app for iOS with Xamarin. Lately, I haven't been able to access my storyboard file in Xcode or compile my app anymore because Xcode crashes right away when opening the .storyboard file.

The error message is the following:

```
ASSERTION FAILURE <br>
Details:  Creating an out of band arbitration unit with a view (<IBUITableViewCell: 0x7fa88d13a5d0>) as the root under another view (<IBUITableView: 0x7fa88cf000e0>) is not yet implemented.<br>The view would need to be in two arbitration units, the one above for positioning constraints, and the root of the one below for sizing constraints. <br>But then that means that subviews cannot have constraints that affect the size of the view, so the view must have ibExternalTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints set to YES.
<br>Object:   <IBUITableViewCell: 0x7fa88d13a5d0>
<br>Method:   -ibArbitrationUnitWasCreatedWithReceiverAsRootUnderParent:
```

I tried rebasing my storyboard to the last version that worked (the one the app was submitted to the app store) and weirdly, even that version didn't work.
My plan was to manually remove and every view controller and add them one by one to figure out where the error is.

However I don't understand why XCode *crashes* when opening the storyboard and not just shows me exactly where the error in my xml is.

So if anyone has encountered this problem before and has a better way to fix it than to manually do it, I would really appreciate any help.

Comment: Which xcode version are you using?Can you please know me how much size of `RAM` in your machine?

Comment: XCode 7.1.1 - so the latest. Tried downgrading to 7.0.1 as well though - didn't help.

Comment: Have you tried to delete your DerivedData folder for your project, that can explain why rebasing didn't work ?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I just tried deleting the folder - xcode still crashes afterwards.

Comment: Try to open storyboard as source code in Xcode. It may has some error ,once you solve them it will be open as interface builder too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ibExternalTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints needs to be YES`

Sounds like the Storyboard was created with an older Xamarin.iOS that introduce this issue.

The *fastest* solution is to open the storyboard in vi (or Xcode / View As Source, or another text editor of your choice, and replace all translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" with "".

Save the file, re-open it in the Storyboard editor and fix your contraints.